# How to create multidimensional array of inner class objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

everything is the title
java tutorial says:

> OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

this doesn't work for me:

```
public class aching{
    class pixel{
        public char c;
        public int f;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        aching a = new aching();
        aching.pixel[][] p = a.new pixel[1][1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just

```
pixel[][] p = new pixel[1][1];
```

It is when you need to create instance of pixel object, you'll have to write:

```
p[0][0] = a.new pixel();
```

Also, it is a good idea to follow common Java naming conventions, e.g. use upper case for class/type names.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   pixel p[][] = new pixel[1][1];

}
```

Further, follow convention, your class names should start with a capital letter.